# Does the improper integral $\int_0^\infty |\sin (x^2)| \; dx$ converge?

Tags: integration, convergence-divergence, absolute-value

I have seen many questions about almost the same integral; the only difference is the absolute value. How can I check if this integral converges (as real integral)? 
$\displaystyle\int_0^\infty |\sin (x^2)| \; dx$

EDIT: I've read [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/13846/443415) in topic you linked, and I don't fully understand the steps in:

> Now we observe that $|\frac{\cos(x)}{2 \sqrt x}|\geq \frac{\cos^2(x)}{2 \sqrt x}=\frac{1}{4\sqrt x}+\frac{\cos(2x)}{4\sqrt x}$.

And this, which arguments?

> By the same arguments above $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(2x)}{4\sqrt x}dx$ converges.

Comment: Try the substitution $y=x^2$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/13823/

Comment: No, it doesn't converge.

Comment: Could you see my edit? I've read that topic and I have a question.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the inequation

$$|\sin x^2|\ge\frac1{\sqrt 2},$$

which is true in the intervals

$$\left[\sqrt{k\frac\pi2-\frac\pi4},\sqrt{k\frac\pi2+\frac\pi4}\right]$$ for odd $k$.

This establishes the bounding

$$\int_0^\infty|\sin x^2|dx\ge{\frac{\sqrt\pi}2}\sum_{\text{odd }k 
}\left(\sqrt{k+\frac12}-\sqrt{k-\frac12}\right).$$

Then

$$\sqrt{k+\frac12}-\sqrt{k-\frac12}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+\dfrac12}+\sqrt{k-\dfrac12}}$$ decays like $\dfrac1{\sqrt k}$, making a divergent sum.

The plot below shows the area that diverges.

[image]